# Adding a refrence to wp8 sdk

Tags: c#, sdk, windows-phone-8

I feel stupid asking this question but how do I add a reference to a project in the WP8 SDK? I need to add `System.Drawing`. Can you please explain it in simple terms as I don't really understand some of this stuff...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System.Drawing** namespace is not available in Windows Phone 8. Most common types from this namespace are located in **System.Windows.Media** namespace, for instance:

```
System.Windows.Media.Color c;
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle r;
System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush b;
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bi;
```